# How to pass data to another app constantly in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gamekit

I just want to know that is it possible to communicate two different apps in different device. Like I have a sample app in device A App name A and in another device B i have a app B I want to share some things between them. I came across to GameKit framework in iOS but I made a app when it is installed in both device they communicate succesfully but what if apps are different and what is the size limit of the data to send it over bluetooth in iOS.

Any idea how to implement this feature?

Comment: These are 3 questions, for which you already stated one answer =) I suggest you split the question in two or how much you need and be a bit more precise about what you want to know.

Comment: Actually i want to know how we can send data to different app on other device in ios using Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two different apps can communicate via Bluetooth using GameKit as long as they both agree on the protocol (i.e. if you wrote both apps, or you know what protocol the other app is using).

There's no limit to the amount of data they can exchange, although there is obviously an upper limit on bandwidth (bytes per second).

Does that help?

Comment: Yea i gonna write both ones but i don't understand by being agree on protocols can you little elaborate me in this any link or any thing that help. Thanks Nick

Comment: I just mean if app A is sending the message "Hello World", app B needs to be set up to receive and process that message. If you are coding both apps yourself it won't be a problem.

Comment: Actually this thing i want to do i want an idea any technical details i little explain my requirement. When app A will run it will find a near by device and search for a application on device b App name B and then make a connection with it then transfer data to that app. Does this explanation can bring  a result for me Nick ? How the app A will understand this is B who is sending me Hello world.

Comment: Well, how did you get it to work when the apps were the same? How did they detect each other?

Comment: I never thought upon it you just reverse my question and i got answer Thanks NICK Thanks you very very much.